# Why symfony assert doesnt work with novalidation attribute on Edit Page?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, assert, symfony-validator

On my form, I am using `novalidate` attribute like this :

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {novalidate: 'novalidate'}}) }}
```

To disable HTML5 browser validation.
So Symfony assert errors appears.
On the new.html.twig page it works perfectly fine! The novalidate attribute disable the html5 validation and the assert errors appear.

But when I use the novalidate attribute on edit.html.twig and leave the `username` field empty (i don't fill it on the form) the `@Assert\NotBlank()` doesn't work. And I get this error

> Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path
> "username".

Why symfony assert work on the **new** page, but it doesnt work on the **edit** page?
By the way, i am not using any validation groups.

here is the code of my User entity(without getters and setters) :

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Email()
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 8, max = 30,
     *      minMessage = "Your password must be between 6 and 30 characters.")     
     */
    private $password;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json", nullable=true )
     */
    private $roles = [];
```

Here is the code of the form :

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class )
            ->add('username', TextType::class)
            ->add('password',PasswordType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

both of new.html.twig and edit.html.twig have the same code :

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {novalidate: 'novalidate'}}) }}    

    {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control',placeholder: 'Email Adress'} }) }}     
    {{form_errors(form.email)}}

    {{ form_widget(form.username, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control',placeholder: 'Username'} }) }}
    {{form_errors(form.username)}}

    {{ form_widget(form.password, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
    {{form_errors(form.password)}}

    <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
{{ form_rest(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Controller code :

```
/**
 * @Route("/new", name="user_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function new(Request $request): Response
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_index');
    }

    return $this->render('user/new.html.twig', [
        'user' => $user,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}


/**
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="user_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function edit(Request $request, User $user): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_index');
    }

    return $this->render('user/edit.html.twig', [
        'user' => $user,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

my getters and setters :

```
public function getEmail(): ?string
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail(string $email): self
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}
public function getUsername(): ?string
{
    return $this->username;
}

public function setUsername(string $username): self
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}


public function getPassword(): ?string
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword(string $password): self
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Hey, if someone else has a better solution I'm also interested. I think you have to add "empty_data" => "" to your username field so the forms returns an empty string instead of null.

Comment: Please edit ur question and add the getters and setters.

Comment: ok i added them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should add `?` sign to the string type on your all setters.

For example change it **From**
`setUsername(string $username): self` **To**  `setUsername(?string $username): self`

This should fix the assert problem on the edit page.